# jquery create list<dictionary<string,string>> object

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a object defined in my C# code behind as

```
 public List<Dictionary<string, string>> attributesList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

now I need to fill this object from Jquery 
That is, in my Jquery file I m getting certain values that I need to fill in this object. 
I am stuck on how to create a JSON object from the following code

```
selectedAttributes.each(function (key, value) {
                    var attributeName = value.attributes.title.value;
                    var attributeValue = $('#' + attributeName + ' option:selected').text();

                });
```

that can be supplied to the attributesList
I need to put (attributeName, attributeValue) pair in the attributelist object

I know I am not clear enough in asking this question, but if any information is required please comment and I'll reply almost instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dictionary would be just an object in JS. You're able to address the items within the dictionary by it's name.

```
 dic['name'] = 'value'; // valid
 dic.name = 'value'; // also valid
 var attrName = 'name';
 dic[attrName] ='value'; // also valid
```

That should be enough info to let you accomplish your task.